# Como puedo mover Origin/main a HEAD en Git

Tags: git, github

[image: Código Git]

Lo que necesito es mover el origin/main al HEAD.
Cuando modifico mis archivos no los esta haciendo en el "origin/main", y lo que necesito es que haga modificaciones en el "HEAD"

¿Cuál seria el comando correcto de Git a utilizar?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para llevar los cambios en ese "detached HEAD" a otra rama debes hacer push a la rama que quieras. Suponiendo que los quieras llevar `main`:

```
git push origin HEAD:main
```

También puedes simplemente crear una rama desde ese HEAD y luego hacer `push`:

```
git checkout -b BRANCH_NAME
git push origin main
```

Comment: Gracias Rubms, sí el primer comando me sirvió.

Comment: Hola @Edin. Si la respuesta te sirvió, debes marcarla como aceptada y, opcionalmente, votarla en positivo. De este modo quien te ayudó aumenta su reputación en el site. Así además el resto de la comunidad verá que la pregunta ya está correctamente respondida y no entrarán para tratar de responderla de nuevo.